Trying to identify my own userID in a Google Drive API request
I'm trying to reuse the TiddlyDrive code but I'm first trying to replicate things manually to make sure I understand things properly. I'm however struggling to get my user ID. This code allows to view an HTML file that's stored on my Google Drive by viewing
tiddlydrive.github.io/?state={ids:[THE_ID_OF_A_FILE],action:open,userId:SOME_DIGITS,resourceKeys:{}}

THE_ID_OF_A_FILE is simple enough to view by opening that very same HTML file in Google Drive (I can just look at the address bar in my browser).
However, I struggle getting the userId (SOME_DIGITS) from anywhere. I tried reading Drive.About.get() and specifically the permissionId but it doesn't match with SOME_DIGITS at all. I tried looking at the client ID I have for some of my projects using GCP, but it likewise doesn't match.
Here's the error if I try the same URL above from another Google account, using another correct file ID of a file located in that account's Google Drive, but using the same SOME_DIGITS userId as from my initial account (so knowing it's not correct, for lack of knowing where to find that ID) so in effect trying to run
tiddlydrive.github.io/?state={ids:[THE_CORRECT_ID_OF_ANOTHER_FILE_FOR_ANOTHER_ACCOUNT],action:open,userId:SOME_DIGITS,resourceKeys:{}}

Error message:
There was an error downloading the file.

This corresponds to the error message returned in index.html by the id "error-msg", itself logically triggered in row 132 of the code linked above (reproduced partially below), which indeed corresponds to an error in fetching the file from Google Drive, unsurprisingly because the userId is incorrect (even if I did get the pop-up to authorise the code to access the Google Drive account).
function fetch_file() {
        var state = JSON.parse(getParameterByName('state'));
        if (state == null) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#nofile-msg').show();
            $('#content').hide();
            return;
        }
        gapi.client.drive.files.get({
            'fileId': state.ids.pop(),
            'alt': 'media'
        }).then(function(file) {
            if (needLegacySrc()) {
                $('#content')[0].contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
                $('#content')[0].contentWindow.document.write(file.body);
                $('#content')[0].contentWindow.document.close();
            } else {
                $('#content')[0].srcdoc = file.body;
            }
            setupSaver();
            $('#loader').hide();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#error-msg').show();
        });
    }

Any clue on how I could retrieve my own userId / SOME_DIGITS? My ultimate goal is to be able to reuse the code (the UserId is perhaps not important) so that I can open a TiddlyWiki HTML file that's located on my Google Drive. I'm not trying to publish the app in the Workspace Marketplace: I instead just would like to run the code for my own private purposes. Thanks!

The code you linked doesn't seem to reference this userid at all.

It doesn't but it somehow retrieves it because I had been using this code via an add-on in Google Drive. But the code is no longer maintained so I would like to understand it better, namely by testing things first hence my question.

If it doesn't work, you would at least need a error message to begin your quest of finding the answer.

Ah yes, good point, thank you, let me edit things.

After line 130, add alert(err) and/or console.log(err) and see browser console(F12 key) to see the actual error.

Thank you, I'll try that. I need to clone the repo to be able to edit the code. Thank you, I'll see what I can find and report back.

I tried to set up a new repo, using my own GCP key and secret and github.io page, but I'm now not even getting to the error. I can authenticate in the settings of the app, but then it just tries to load without showing anything on screen or in the console. I tried adding console.log for many variables across the script, but alas it's not showing anything in the console either. The code isn't super complicated or long, but I am unable to figure out how to make it work still...
